# Composer show output is different if echoed or redirected to a file

Tags: bash, shell, composer-php

I try to make a .sh file that list all my no-dev package and then copy them to an other repository.
So I come with this code :

```bash
#!/bin/sh
list_of_all_no_dev_package=$(composer show --no-dev --name-only)
for no_dev_package in $list_of_all_no_dev_package; do
  cp -r "vendor/${no_dev_package}" "${export_path}/vendor/${no_dev_package}"
done
```

To ensure my cp command is fine, I tried to echo it in my terminal and got something like

`cp -r "vendor/mypackage" "myexportpath/vendor/mypackage"`

However, if I try to redirect the output to a text file with the >> operator, I got something very different

`cp -r "vendor/https://github.com/mypackage/tree/master/whateverfile.php" "myexportpath/vendor/https://github.com/mypackage/tree/master/whateverfile.php`

How can I get the first output with a composer command and why are those 2 results so different?

Comment: Everything revolves around the results of the `composer` command.  Run that only to see what it outputs and fix your code accordingly.  You might have to somehow parse and cleanup that output.

Comment: I'd recommend at least two additional flags for invocation: `composer -n --no-plugins show ...` which are (1.) `-n` non-interactive (as that is in your script) and (2.) `--no-plugins` to disable plugins to prevent side-effects. Those are global composer arguments, that is you place them before the composer command (here: `show`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to occur on recent composer installation. It does happend on actual latest : 2.4.1 but does not on 2.1.2

Using `composer show --name-only` actually return a result with the full repository path (github or whatever has been set up in the config files) and add 2 ESC char in it. The CLI then prints what's between those 2 ESC char.

Solution is to add the global option `--no-ansi`

`composer show --name-only --no-dev --no-ansi` will return the directory name of the repository in your vendor folder.

Answer (score 2):

If simple command substitution does not work right out of the box for you (which can happen), I'd consider - next to improving shell debugging skills - to get composers output more stable.

The one part I already placed as a comment, in shell scripts the following global arguments:

1. use `-n` to make composer non-interactive if that is the intended use. this keeps many issues out of the factory.
2. use `--no-ansi` to make composer not output ansi escape sequences (for coloring the output).
3. use `--no-plugins` to disable plugins, you want to keep those out as well in scripts.

In addition to those run-time-behaviour controlling arguments there is also one for the output. This is helpful if you want to ensure it is machine-readable. For example you can get the installed package names as JSON Text:

```
$ composer -n --no-plugins --format=json show --no-dev --name-only
{
    "installed": [
        {
            "name": "composer/ca-bundle"
        },
        {
            "name": "composer/metadata-minifier"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

You can then use a utility to pipe the result into that is able to parse JSON Text and error out otherwise, e.g. `jq(1)` or `php(1)`. Here an example w/ PHP (7.0+) as it is likely already available:

```
$ composer -n --no-plugins --format=json show --no-dev --name-only \
| php -r \
'  echo implode("\n", array_column('\
'    json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN))->installed, '\
'    "name")) ?? exit(1), "\n";'
composer/ca-bundle
composer/metadata-minifier
...
```

This then is a good filter to further process the data in your script.

Do a strict validation of the composer.json before running any of such scripts as here you want to ensure that all package names are strictly conforming with the portable composer package name profile that is now in effect since a couple of releases (but I have no idea how deep it scans, otherwise `pathchk(1)` comes to mind).

Full example with some shell debugging and error handling:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
set -x

list_of_all_no_dev_package=$(
  composer -nq --no-plugins validate --strict >&2 &&
    composer -n --no-ansi --no-plugins --format=json show --no-dev --name-only |
      php -r 'echo
          implode($terminator = "\n",
              array_column(
                  json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN))->installed,
                  "name"
              )
          ) ?? exit(1),
          $terminator
        ;
      '
) || exit

for no_dev_package in $list_of_all_no_dev_package; do
  printf "no dev package: '%s'\n" "${no_dev_package}" >&2
  cp -r "vendor/${no_dev_package}" \
        "${export_path?:export_path unset}/vendor/${no_dev_package}"
done
```

---

And if you consider to actually use `/bin/bash` check your bash version, there are arrays and you can read them in, compare [*shellharden etc.*](https://github.com/anordal/shellharden/blob/master/how_to_do_things_safely_in_bash.md#the-first-thing-to-know-about-bash-coding).

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, problem was actually solved with a simplier solution by just adding --no-ansi to the `composer show` cmd

Comment: Why use `set -e` for exactly one command? You could just as easily do `that_command || exit`, with exactly the same effect. (Yes, this works for assignments with command substitutions; as long as you don't use a keyword like `local`, `export`, `declare`, etc, that command substitution's exit status passes through).

Comment: I would also suggest using an array; f/e, `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a packages < <(composer -nq ... | php ... && printf '\0') || exit` is compatible back through bash 3.2, will properly fail if the `printf '\0'` doesn't get invoked, and gives you your list as an array: you can get the count of items in it with `"${#packages[@]}"`, iterate through them without the bugs that come with word splitting with `"${packages[@]}"`, etc. ([DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) discusses aforementioned "bugs that come with word splitting" in more detail).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for the insightful reminders, the why is likely my shell script hacking skills. `set -e` use is as the command is complex and a pipe involved. Given `/bin/sh` I was under the impression as `pipefail` might not be available and it helped me build up the complex command. As now its ready and the last command fails if the input is not parse-able as JSON text and with the structure, it should not be necessary. I've updated. Using the array is only if an array is available, given `/bin/sh` I didn't suggest it and only references shellharden etc. which shows such use.

Comment: @ViLar: Right, I had `--no-ansi` not on the table. The versions I tested with were not affected by ansi escape sequences. This must be something relatively new. All kids love colors thought, so whom to blame. I edited it in as well.

Comment: Right that pipefail doesn't exist in baseline POSIX sh, but `set -e` only fails in a very limited set of cases -- it doesn't track every pipeline component. See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), skipping the analogy for the exercises below if in a hurry.

Comment: ...that said, this question is tagged bash, so `/bin/sh` compatibility shouldn't be needed -- if it is, the OP mistagged.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for pointing to BashFAQ #105 and its good to be aware of the set -e details. There is also more QA material on site and IIRC Posix also outlines this. It may be the OP mistagged however it does not hurt if at the end of the day the code is portable IMHO, so it must not be a question which /bin/sh. Perhaps its in Nix then it is perfectly tagged for the original example.